# css external file doesn't do anything

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my page but nothing happens. I think that my css code is wrong. This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<ul>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="downloads.html">Download Links</a></li>
</ul>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css/">
<div id="footer">
<div class="container">
<div class="column">
<h4>My Links</h4>
<p>
<a href="https://web.facebook.com/YousefRaedXD" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
<br>
<a href ="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6x7kvBibYzem6i59UMc3kw" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
<h4>My Story</h4>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</head>
</html>
```

This is my css code:

```
#header-nav li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 20px;
}
#header-nav {
display: block;
float:right;
margin-top:0;
}
#header {
background-color: #1abc9c;
height: 150px;
line-height: 150px;
}
.container {
max-width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
}
#header-title {
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#header a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;

text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
#header a:hover {
color: #222;
}
```

I keep my files in desktop in a file:
[image: here]

Where is a problem in my code?

Comment: you didn't declare `#header-title,#header,#header-nav`

Comment: So .. what is the correct code to write

Comment: when you select an element, do you see the specified styles in the browser object inspector (F12)?

Comment: `#` is for id. if you want to style an element that has specific id, `hello` for example you should declare what element had this id. like this: `<element id="hello"/>` and css: `#hello{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html needs tidying up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="header">
   <ul id="header-nav">
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="downloads.html">Download Links</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
   <div class="container">

    <div class="column">
     <h4>My Links</h4>
     <p>
      <a href="https://web.facebook.com/YousefRaedXD" target="_blank">Facebook</a><br>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6x7kvBibYzem6i59UMc3kw" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
     <h4>My Story</h4>
     <p></p>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

You also need to make sure you refer to your classes in the css file. At the moment I can only see .container. You don't have header id anywhere in your html.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work! i think the css is messed up..

Comment: I have updated the html now with IDs you have in CSS, it should help you to get started. I have added "header-nav" and "header" ids, which you have in CSS, but don't have in HTML yet. That's why it does not work, because there is no elements references in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Please do write your code in a readable format, indentation is very important not only to yourself, but to everyone who might read it ESPECIALLY when you are asking people where the problem may be as it would ease the process for everyone, that would be appreciated.

Problems I have noticed:

**In the HTML file**:

1. The "head" tag is used for meta-data; document title, linking to CSS file and other information that is not displayed on the page.
2. All of the nested tags in the "head" should be instead be nested on the "body"  tag except for the "link" tag.
3. I don't understand why there is an empty paragraph tag.

**In the CSS file**:

1. The last slash in your href attribute is what is causing trouble, removing it will link the CSS to the HTML (If the file is in the correct directory).
2. You are referencing nonexistent elements by using "#header-nav", "#header", "#header-title" none of which are valid ID names.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of errors in your code-

1. You haven't linked your CSS file to your HTML
2. Your HTML body is missing and instead all the codes are there in the head
3. In your CSS file, you haven't referred to classes or containers, you have used # which is used for referencing ids which are not in your HTML code.